# How to find out object keys are string or Array in javascript

Tags: javascript

This is my JSON,Now i want to find out the properties are array or string .

{
    "data":[

```
{ 

     "name": "my Service", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"

}, 

 { 
     "name": "my Service1", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"
},

 { 

     "name": "my Service2", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"
},

 { 

     "name": "my Service3", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"
}
```

]
}

Now how to find out the properties are string or array.

Comment: Please clarify your question a bit with more description... what are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @BanjoMofesolaPaul I am trying  write a function to find out properties are string or array  from above  JSON.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As i understood your answer as you need to identify each property type. 
I have done like below code. please let me know if i'm not in your route. I just consoled all the types

```js
var data = [

{ 

     "name": "my Service", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"

}, 

 { 
     "name": "my Service1", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"
},

 { 

     "name": "my Service2", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"
},

 { 

     "name": "my Service3", 
     "description":"   comes once here  " , 
     "tables":{ "tables":["rajaaaaa ","rajuuuuu","mommmm"]},
     "imgUrl":"../assets/images/nmpm.jpg"
}
];


data.forEach(obj=>{
 
   var keys = Object.keys(obj);
   for(var k=0;k< keys.length; k++){
      if(typeof obj[keys[k]] == 'string'){
           console.log(keys[k]+" is string");
      }else if(typeof obj[keys[k]] == 'object'){
          
           
            var obj_keys = Object.keys(obj[keys[k]]);
           
            for(var j = 0; j< obj_keys.length; j++){
            
           
             if(Object.prototype.toString.call( obj[keys[k]][obj_keys[j]] ) === '[object Array]') {
               console.log(keys[k]+" has Array");
             }
            }
           
      }
      
     
   }
 
});
```

Comment: Yes this is what i am expecting,Now  I would like to store all string in one variable and arrays in other variable and  i will to html .

Answer (score 0):

The check for string is:

```
typeof var === 'string'
```

The check for array is:

```
Object.prototype.toString().call(var) === '[object Array]'
```

Comment: I would like to check for both array and string ,I wish to write a function to find out which is array and string .

Comment: Edited my answer

Comment: Why not `Array.isArray()`?